# Type inference: functions vs types

Tags: f#

I am learning F# and I don't understand how type inference and generics work in this language. For example, I can declare a generic min function and use it with parameters of different types:

```
let min a b = if a < b then a else b

let smallestInt = min 3 5
let smallestFloat = min 3.0 5.0
```

But if I try the same thing with a type, it doesn't work:

```
type Point2D(x, y) = 
    member this.X = x
    member this.Y = y

let float32Point = new Point2D(0.0f, 1.0f)
let intPoint = new Point2D(0, 1) // This expression was expected to have type 
                                 // float32 but here has type int
```

So, I have a few questions:

- Why can I re-use the generic function definition for different types but not the type definition?
- Is the function specialized for every type at run-time like with C# generics? Or at compile-time like C++ templates? Or is boxing performed to treat every argument as IComparable?

Thanks.

Comment: This is called [automatic generalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx).

Comment: @svick Automatic generalization means inferring general types but there is more going on here than just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes require explicit type parameters. This works:

```
type Point2D<'T>(x:'T, y:'T) = 
    member this.X = x
    member this.Y = y

let float32Point = Point2D(0.0f, 1.0f)
let intPoint = Point2D(0, 1)
```

To answer your second question, your definition of `min` has the signature `'a -> 'a -> 'a (requires comparison)`. The `comparison` constraint exists only at compile-time (the run-time signature is the same, minus the constraint).

`<` is replaced with a call to `GenericLessThanIntrinsic`, which has the constraint. The constraint is merely propagated to callers.

Also, from section 14.6.7 of the spec:

> Generalization is the process of inferring a generic type for a definition where possible, thereby making the construct reusable with multiple different types. **Generalization is applied by default at all function, value, and member definitions**, except where listed later in this section. Generalization also applies to member definitions that implement generic virtual methods in object expressions.

*(emphasis added)*

Notice, classes are missing from the list. I suppose it doesn't give the rationale, but it *is* by design.