# Generic functions in F#

Tags: generics, f#, automatic-generalization

I'm still trying to wrap my head around how F# generalizes (or not) functions and types, and there's a case that's bugging me:

```
let min(a, b) = if a < b then a else b

let add(a, b) = a + b

let minInt = min(3, 4)
let minFloat = min(3.0, 4.0) // works!

let addInt = add(3, 5)
let addFloat = add(3.0, 5.0) // error: This expression was expected to have type
                             // int but here has type float
```

Here min has the generic type `'a * 'a -> 'a (requires comparison)` while add has a concrete type `int * int -> int`, apparently inferred from its first use in the program. Both are declared and used in the same way, so why the difference in generalization?

I understand that in the case of add, the problem can be side-stepped by declaring the function inline, which causes it to get a generic type definition, i.e. `'a * 'b -> 'c (requires member (+))`, but that doesn't explain why this is needed in this case and not the other.

Comment: The compiler has abstracted the concept of "comparable"; it has not abstracted the concept of "addable". `<` is the odd one out here, not `+`.

Comment: Why do you expect uses of `+` and `<` to generate the same signature?

Comment: @Daniel I don't expect the same signature (although in this particular case it would make sense, but that's not the point); I expect that either both should be generic or neither. Here one is concrete and the other is generic without apparent reason.

Comment: See this for background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588506/type-inference-functions-vs-types/10588667#10588667

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an excellent write up on this very issue by @TomasP here: http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx

> When writing simple generic code that has some type parameter 'T, we
>   don’t know anything about the type parameter and there is no way to
>   restrict it to a numeric type that provides all the operators that we
>   may need to use in our code. This is a limitation of the .NET runtime
>   and F# provides two ways for overcoming it.

But why are `<` and `>` (and by extension, `=`, `<=` and `>=`) OK?

The F# compiler treats `equality` and `comparison` differently (see section 5.2.10 Equality and Comparison Constraints in the [specs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997037), thanks @Daniel). You get the **special** `comparison` constraint, which is allowed when (simply, see the spec for more detail):

> If the type is a named type, then the type definition does not have,
>   and is not inferred to have, the NoComparison attribute, and the type
>   definition implements System.IComparable or is an array type or is
>   System.IntPtr or is System.UIntPtr.

There is no such special handling for the `+` operator. Why couldn't there be a constraint such as `numeric`?

Well isn't that operator also defined for strings? In some languages for lists and collections? Surely it would be an `addable` constraint and not `numeric`. Then many such overloaded operators can be found in a program with different semantic meaning. So F# provides a 'catch-all' method with static member constraints and the inline keyword. Only `equality` and `comparison` are special.

Comment: So, in general, does F# automatically look for constraints that allow for keeping types generic, or is this specific to a set of pre-defined operators?

Comment: In general F# will try and make the types as generic as possible for how they are used. However, it can't cheat the .NET framework and define a generic for the concept of 'number' - there is no relevant interface that it can constrain to!

Comment: @yamen: The `comparison` constraint doesn't generate something like `where T : IComparable` in C#. It exists at compile-time only and is less restrictive. See the [relevant section of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997037).

Comment: Yes, it's a bit different - but from the spec "it usually implies that a type must implement System.IComparable". I'll update for accuracy.

Comment: I mentioned it because it seems to refute the thrust of your answer: that `comparison` is inherent in .NET and math ops are not. Your answer doesn't so much give the rationale for the difference (I don't see why there _couldn't_ be something like `requires numeric`) as much as explain the different implementation mechanisms.

Comment: I've been updating the answer. Yes, `equality` and `comparison` are special. Why couldn't there be something for `+`? Well isn't that operator also defined for strings? In some languages for lists and collections? Surely it would be an `addable` constraint and not `numeric`. Many such constraints can be found in a program, so F# provides a 'catch-all' method with static member constraints and the `inline` keyword.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I suspect generic math ops are inlined mostly for performance and the constraints are just a by-product.

Answer (score 2):

> why the difference in generalization?

There is a trade-off between generality and performance. The `comparison` constraint provides generality for functions like `min` that can act upon any value of any F# type but in the general case it resorts to virtual dispatch and is many times slower. The `+` operator provides restricted generality and can act upon any value of any F# type that has been augmented with an overload but does not work in the general case and, therefore, is always very fast because dispatch is never needed.

Answer (score 1):

`comparison` is a compile-time constraint. So the question remains: why isn't `add` generalized? As yamen pointed out, generic math ops require inlining, which affects code size and performance—probably not something the compiler should do automatically.

Comment: Affects code size negatively but performance positively. I don't know if there are other trade-offs.